# Clang 6 on travis breaks due to libjsoncpp0

Tags: c++, clang, travis-ci

The travis ci for our build has broken due to the following problem:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clang-6.0 : Depends: libjsoncpp0 (>= 0.6.0~rc2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
apt-get.diagnostics
apt-get install failed
```

`sudo apt install libjsoncpp0` doesn't work as `libjsoncpp0` doesn't exist; and I also tried `sudo apt install libjsoncpp-dev` succeeds, but doesn't solve the problem.

How can I install `libjsoncpp0` on travis?

[Build log](https://travis-ci.org/boostorg/math/jobs/546204079), [travis.yml](https://github.com/boostorg/math/blob/develop/.travis.yml).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I have similar [problem](https://travis-ci.org/gelldur/EventBus/builds/547416111) with `clang-6.0` on Travis in my [EventBus library](https://github.com/gelldur/EventBus). This just happen without any changes. Probably issue is in the default distro which is picked as: Trusty [(here they mention this)](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/overview/#linux)

I fixed issue in this way:

```
# clang-6
- os: linux
  name: "Xenial - clang 6"
  dist: xenial
  env: [USE_CC='/usr/bin/clang-6.0', USE_CXX='/usr/bin/clang++-6.0']
  addons:
    apt:
      packages: ['clang-6.0', 'cmake']
      sources: ['ubuntu-toolchain-r-test']
```

Seems to work as you can [see here](https://travis-ci.org/gelldur/EventBus)
Link to my full [.travis.yml](https://github.com/gelldur/EventBus/blob/master/.travis.yml)

[Travis documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/cpp/) about building C++ projects feels little bit old.

---

So the final result is:

[image]